# How to send data in DD.MM.YY format?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a filter by date. In datepicker, the date should be displayed in the format that is currently set. But when sending a date, the date should be in the format `DD.MM.YY` (24.07.19).

But sent in this format:

```
Wed Jul 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0500
```

How to change the format that should go?

html:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [(ngModel)]="search" placeholder="Date" required>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
  <button mat-icon-button matSuffix color="primary" (click)="applyFilter()" matTooltip="Seacrh">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button matSuffix color="accent" (click)="clear()" matTooltip="Clear">
    <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
export const FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YY',
  }
}

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: FORMAT }
  ]
})
```

Comment: What did you try ? I'll give you a hint : you can use `Adapter` pattern with angular material.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a custom pipe which extends `DatePipe` like this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customDateFormat'
})
export class CustomDateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return super.transform(value, 'dd/MM/yy');
  }
}
```

and then injecting it in your component's constructor and using, for example, like this:

```
constructor(private _dateFormatPipe: DateFormatPipe) {
}

applyFilter() {
  alert(this._dateFormatPipe.transform(this.search));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adapter pattern](https://christianlydemann.com/using-the-adapter-pattern-in-angular-apps-for-easier-maintenance/) with angular material.
To change the date format, you can implement those javascript functions inside a typescript helper class for example.

```js
function to2digit(n) {
    return ('00' + n).slice(-2);
}

function toCustomDateFormat(date) {
    if (!date) {
      return '';
    }
    const day = date.getDate();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    return `${to2digit(day)}.${to2digit(month)}.${to2digit(year)}`;
}

const dateNow = new Date();

console.log(`${dateNow} => ${toCustomDateFormat(dateNow)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment js to reformat the date string as follows:

```
import * as _moment from 'moment';

let t = _moment('Wed Jul 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0500').format("DD.MM.YY");
```

And then transmit the reformated date string.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass simply this [working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/momentjs-format-date)

```
let now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  let now2 = moment().format("DD.MM.YYYY");
     this.format1 = now;
     this.format2 = now2;
     console.log(now);
```

.html

```
<h4>format dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss </h4>
<h4>{{ format1 }} </h4>

<h4>formated your dd.mm.yyyy </h4>
<h4>{{ format2 }} </h4>

<p>Date : {{date}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuild DatePipe:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'  // Import this

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) { } // In constructor

this.saveDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.newDate, 'dd.MM.yy');
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj7rkh)

Answer (score 0):

My code is

.ts

```
export class ... {
     get date(): any { return this.Form.get('date'); } /* get value from <mat-form-field> */

  onSubmit() {
     const formatdate = moment(this.date.value).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
     console.log(formatdate );
  }
}
```

In onSubmit function I convert default format to moment format for POST to api backend.